# creating UEFI USB Boot stick using rufus option gives errors

Tags: boot, usb, uefi, gpt, rufus

I am trying to install windows 7 from a USB UEFI stick that I tried to create in vain. 
I read other posts on creating UEFI USB Boot sticks and found Rufus the most convenient option . However , Rufus won't allow me a choice of GPT method and Fat32. It complains that it needs a UEFI ISO image.

[image]

So I gather , from this that my ISO does not have the typical EFI files. How do I get these files and what files are needed. What I have is a multiboot ISO that lets you choose between 64 and 32 bit versions. 
Dir structure is like this

```
Drive letter
Boot
EFI 
source64
sources 
etc
```

Under EFI

```
Microsoft --> Boot --> Fonts(d),Bcd (file)
```

Under Boot

```
en-us,fonts,bcd(file),boot.sdi,bootfix.bin,bootsect.exe,etfsboot.com,memtest.exe
```

Is this is an issue with missing EFI files is there a way I can download them , alternately can I use  GRUB BASED EFI Loader to boot dual boot windows 8 and windows 7 on a EFI Laptop. Just to clarify windows 8 is pre-installed.Windows 7 needs to be installed  as dual boot option to windows 8 using a UEFI USB stick .

Comment: If a solution _without_ any third party tools is ok for you, [this](https://superuser.com/a/1627333/1077440) is a way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

It won’t work because you have a non-official ISO image. You need an unmodified Windows 7 x64 ISO image. Windows 7 x86 aka 32-bit is not UEFI-compatible.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach:

1. Create your USB bios boot key with [Windows USB/DVD Download
       Tool](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/windows-usb-dvd-download-tool) and use the Microsoft Windows 8 ISO
2. Move all the content off the key to a temporary location
3. Format the USB key to FAT32 (use diskmgmt.msc or diskpart for this)
4. Move the files from the temporary location onto the USB key
5. Disable "Legacy BIOS"
6. Boot on the USB key
7. When the install wizard starts, press Shift+F10 to open the Command Prompt.
   From here, you can execute diskpart, then use "clean" & "convert GPT" subcommand, etc.

Enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

Try the following procedure **to create an UEFI USB Boot Stick without any extra software**:

1. Attach your USB stick to the PC (it has to be 4GB or larger)
2. Press -> Windows Key + R
3. Type then hit enter -> diskpart (a command prompt will open)
4. Type in the black window -> list disk
5. Find your USB disk (example: disk 1)
6. Type -> sel disk N (where N is the number of the identified disk in the previous step)
7. Type -> clean
8. Type -> create part primary
9. Type -> assign
10. Type -> active
11. Type -> format fs=FAT32 quick **(it'll erase everything in your USB sick)**
12. You can close the diskpart
13. Mount the image of Windows you have, open it and copy everything to the USB stick.
14. Done!

**Make sure the disk you select is the USB Stick by verifying the size to avoid loss of data.**

Answer (score 0):

Windows 7 and older Windows Versions do not support UEFI. They still support the BIOS. Hence the ISO does not come preloaded with UEFI boot images for your motherboard to recognize. That's the reason RUFUS doesn't allows you to write the ISO.

You have no option available!

Comment: That’s simply not true. Windows 7 x64 supports UEFI.

Comment: Win7 x64 does support   UEFI. Win7 x86 doesn't support UEFI. So rufis gives that .. Or maybe it doesn't support GPT..  It doesn't support the option of GPT with UEFI in Rufus that's for sure.